# I have this function im getting an error on the last line: return l; what could it be?

Tags: c#

```
 public static long[] GetHistogramRGB(Bitmap b)
        {
            long[] myHistogramBlue = new long[256];
            long[] myHistogramGreen = new long[256];
            long[] myHistogramRed = new long[256];
            BitmapData bmData = null;

            try
            {
                //Lock it fixed with 32bpp
                bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                int scanline = bmData.Stride;
                System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
                unsafe
                {
                    byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
                    int nWidth = b.Width;
                    int nHeight = b.Height;
                    for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
                        {
                            long Temp = 0;
                            Temp += p[0];
                            myHistogramBlue[Temp]++;

                            long Temp2 = 0;
                            Temp2 += p[1];
                            myHistogramGreen[Temp2]++;

                            long Temp3 = 0;
                            Temp3 += p[2];
                            myHistogramRed[Temp3]++;

                            //we do not need to use any offset, we always can increment by pixelsize when
                            //locking in 32bppArgb - mode
                            p += 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
                b.UnlockBits(bmData);
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    b.UnlockBits(bmData);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            List<long[]> l = new List<long[]>();
            l.Add(myHistogramBlue);
            l.Add(myHistogramGreen);
            l.Add(myHistogramRed);

            return l;

        }
```

On the last line return l; im getting the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<long[]>' to 'long[]'
```

### How can i fix it ?

I tried to do it this way:

```
public static long[] GetHistogramRGB(Bitmap b)
        {
            long[] myHistogramBlue = new long[256];
            long[] myHistogramGreen = new long[256];
            long[] myHistogramRed = new long[256];
            BitmapData bmData = null;

            try
            {
                //Lock it fixed with 32bpp
                bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                int scanline = bmData.Stride;
                System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
                unsafe
                {
                    byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
                    int nWidth = b.Width;
                    int nHeight = b.Height;
                    for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
                        {
                            long Temp = 0;
                            Temp += p[0];
                            myHistogramBlue[Temp]++;

                            long Temp2 = 0;
                            Temp2 += p[1];
                            myHistogramGreen[Temp2]++;

                            long Temp3 = 0;
                            Temp3 += p[2];
                            myHistogramRed[Temp3]++;

                            //we do not need to use any offset, we always can increment by pixelsize when
                            //locking in 32bppArgb - mode
                            p += 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
                b.UnlockBits(bmData);
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    b.UnlockBits(bmData);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            var l = new Dictionary<string, long[]>();
            l.Add("blue", myHistogramBlue);
            l.Add("green", myHistogramGreen);
            l.Add("red", myHistogramRed);

            return l;

        }

Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,long[]>' to 'long[]'
```

And im calling using this function now in another class like this:

```
long[] HistogramsValuesRGB = Form1.GetHistogramRGB(original_bmp);
```

And this dosen't give any errors the error is in the function it self in Form1 on the return l;

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to concatenate those arrays?

Comment: Default locale i want to get three Lists each List is an Histogram of the color from the Bitmap b. The first List will be the R of the Bitmap b the second will be G and then B. RGB colors from the Bitmap B so in the end i will be able to use each List(Histogram) color of the Bitmap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `l` is a list of arrays, but the return type of your structure is a single array.

If you need to return a single array:

```
List<long> l = new List<long>();
l.AddRange(myHistogramBlue);
l.AddRange(myHistogramGreen);
l.AddRange(myHistogramRed);

return l.ToArray();
```

If you need to return a *list* of arrays, change the return type from `long[]` to `List<long[]>`. Though in this case, I would probably use a `Dictionary<string,long[]>` to store each array against a name:

```
var l = new Dictionary<string,long[]>();
l.Add("blue", myHistogramBlue);
l.Add("green", myHistogramGreen);
l.Add("red", myHistogramRed);
```

Comment: Oded i tried your code the one with the string but im getting an error on the return l; i just updated my question with that. I also tried return l.toArray(); but im getting also an error.

Comment: @DanielLip - It is really unclear what you are trying to do, so difficult to give an answer that will suit your needs. Please explain what you are trying to achieve. You say you get errors, but I can't read what's on your monitor - what errors?

Comment: Oded what i want to do is to get three Lists each one will be an histogram of a the same Bitmap b all the histograms should be the r.g.b of the Bitmap so the first List should be the histogram of the R of the bitmap b the second list should be the g of the same bitmap b and the last one should be b of the same bitmap b. I want to get the histogram of the r.g.b colors from the bitmap b. So later i will be able to use each of the histograms alone the R the G and the B.

Comment: @DanielLip - I would say that the dictionary approach is probably most suitable, as you can then access each histogram by a string. You need to ensure that the return type of the function and the type of the variable you are returning match. That's the issue with your code and probably still the issue with changes you have made.

Comment: I changed the function type to: Dictionary<string,Long[]> and it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel: Don't use `Long` - use `long` (they both compile to the same IL, but `long` is more C#ish).

Answer (score 1):

You method is supposed to return an array of longs (`long[]`).

You are trying to return a List of arrays of longs (`List<long[]>`).

You can either:

A) Change the method signature to return `List<long[]>`

or

B) Flatteren the list of longs into a array of longs using `SelectMany()`.
i.e.

```
return l.SelectMany(v => v).ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

C) What @Oded suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is not the same type as your function:

```
functiontype:  long[]
return type: List<long[]>
```

Change one of them to match the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your ordering needs...

```
for(int i = 0; i < myHistogramBlue.Length; i++)
{
l.Add(myHistogramBlue[i]);
l.Add(myHistogramGreen[i]);
l.Add(myHistogramRed[i]);
}

return l.toArray();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return value is `long[]` and your returning a `List<long[]>`

change the declaration to:

```
public static List<long[]> GetHistogramRGB(Bitmap b)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return `l.ToArray();` the return types in your code `long[]  , List<long[]>` are incompatible.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to return a

```
List<long[]>
```

as

```
long[]
```

Replace your code:

```
List<long> l = new List<long>();
l.Add(myHistogramBlue);
l.Add(myHistogramGreen);
l.Add(myHistogramRed);

return l.ToArray();
```